# visual foxpro report error file in use

Tags: visual-foxpro

i have created exe file connector (called it directory server.exe) from server (original exe called abi.exe) to client pc, the connector i created was using set default and set path to, i copy the directory server (connector) and abi.exe to the client pc. input the server address and client address.
the abi.exe was working good. until i want to print report on my client pc (set up margin). so i copy again the report.frx (called faktur1.frx) to client pc along with the abi.exe. i opened the faktur1.frx, it show some error "file in use"
some help will be great. thanks and sorry for the bad english.

---

```
IF FILE('clientuser.mem')
RESTORE FROM clientuser ADDITIVE
mz_dir = RTRIM(zdirserver)
mx_dir = RTRIM(zdirclient)
ELSE
mz_dir = ''
mx_dir = ''
ENDIF
thisform.defa.value = mz_dir
thisform.path.value = mx_dir
```

i used that syntax and ended report error "file in use" when i copied the report from server to client pc, sorry for bad english

Comment: Since you are doing things in a very convoluted manner which doesn't make much sense to me, rather than telling us what you put together and which doesn't work, why not tell us quite basically what you want to accomplish and we might point to a whole other way of approaching your goal. The assumption here (since you don't tell us) is that you are doing all of this in Visual Foxpro.

Comment: Additionally to what @Dhugalmac stated, copying a report is TWO PARTS... and FRX and FRT file.  They are in pairs like scx/sct, vcx/vct, dbf/cdx/fpt.  You only copied one half of the report.